# Prove that $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\sin \left(nx\right)\cos \left(nt\right)\left(-\frac{\cos \left(n\pi \right)-1}{2\pi n}\right) = \frac{1}{4}e^{4t}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

If I've calculated it correctly, it should be equal to that, but I don't know how to check it as WolframAlpha does not want to calculate it

So how can I know if I am right or wrong?

Comment: Is the result really independent of $x$? Doesn’t hold for $x=0$.

Comment: I think I indeed did a mistake, I tried to calculate A and B in \begin{equation}
  \begin{cases}
    w\left(x,0\right)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty \:}\sin \left(nx\right)\cdot \left(\tilde{A}_n\right)=\frac{1}{4}\\
    w_x\left(0,t\right)=\sum \:\:_{n=1}^{\infty \:\:}n\cdot \left(\tilde{A}_n\cos \left(nt\right)+\tilde{B}_n\sin \left(nt\right)\right)=0\\
    w_x\left(\pi ,t\right)=\sum \:\:_{n=1}^{\infty \:\:}n\cdot \left(-1\right)^n\cdot \left(\tilde{A}_n\cos \left(nt\right)+\tilde{B}_n\sin \left(nt\right)\right)=0
  \end{cases}
\end{equation} 
and I got A=(-cos...) and B=0. Im sure A is correct

Comment: I tried to calculate B how we did during class, but now I see that it's absolutely not applicable to that problem. So yeah, I don't know how to calculate B. I definitely know that 1/4 exp (4t) must be the result for w(x,t), that's 100% sure as I've checked the solutions

Comment: For $w\left(x,t\right)=\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }w_n\left(x,t\right)=\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\sin \left(nx\right)\cdot \left(\tilde{A}_n\cos \left(nt\right)+\tilde{B}_n\sin \left(nt\right)\right)$ of course

Comment: It is impossible that the sum does not depend on $x$. Hence the claim is wrong and cannot be proved.

Comment: Ok, my mistake is more fundamental than I thought. This question can be closed

Comment: Ok, I've corrected my calculations and it should be $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\left(\frac{1}{2} \cos ^2\left(nx\right)e^{\left(4-n^2\right)t}\right)$ instead. Would this be true?